# How do I randomize my questions? I can't find an answer anywhere else

Tags: javascript

```
// create questions
var questions = [
    new Question("Which one is not an object oriented programming language?", ["Java", "C#","C++", "C"], "C"),
    new Question("Which language is used for styling web pages?", ["HTML", "JQuery", "CSS", "XML"], "CSS"),
    new Question("There are ____ main components of object oriented programming.", ["1", "6","2", "4"], "4"),
    new Question("Which language is used for web apps?", ["PHP", "Python", "Javascript", "All"], "All"),
    new Question("MVC is a ____.", ["Language", "Library", "Framework", "All"], "Framework")
];


// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);
```

how to randomize when the quiz is created ^^^
the `[Math.floor(math.random()*]` doesn't work

Comment: you can use lodash method shuffle: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle

Comment: or you can randomize all the array like this questions.sort((a, b) => Math.random() - 0.5). BTW the last question doesn't contain the right answer :) (it should be 'design pattern')

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
// create questions
var questions = [
    new Question("Which one is not an object oriented programming language?", ["Java", "C#","C++", "C"], "C"),
    new Question("Which language is used for styling web pages?", ["HTML", "JQuery", "CSS", "XML"], "CSS"),
    new Question("There are ____ main components of object oriented programming.", ["1", "6","2", "4"], "4"),
    new Question("Which language is used for web apps?", ["PHP", "Python", "Javascript", "All"], "All"),
    new Question("MVC is a ____.", ["Language", "Library", "Framework", "All"], "Framework")
];


// create quiz
let randomQuestion = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length)]
var quiz = new Quiz(randomQuestion);
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
    at populate (/app.js:8:52)
    at /app.js:59:1